# dropdown button exception in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, drop-down-menu

I am creating a mobile application using `Flutter` and `Dropdown` button. Dropdown button exception is occurred.

```
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 1206 pos 12: 'widget.items!.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == widget.value).length == 1': is not true.
```

I am sharing the code snapshot.

```
DropdownButton(  
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem(    
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Green",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(    
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Blue",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(   
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Black",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(    
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Red",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
  onChanged: (val) {},
)
```

Is there any way to fix the issue? Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 1):

Both `DropdownButton` and `DropdownMenuItem` have `value` parameter is the parameter that will be displayed as selected value. There should be only one `DropdownMenuItem` with that `value`  in the `item` list(not more or less than one). That is what flutter is complaining about. You have forgot to pass that `value` parameter to both of them.
I have corrected it for you as follows,

```
    DropdownButton<String>( 
  hint: "Select a color", 
  value: dropdownValue,
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem<String>( 
      value : "green",   
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Green",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(    
      value : "blue",  
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Blue",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(   
      value: "black",
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Black",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(   
      value : "red", 
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Red",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
  onChanged: (val) {
    if(val != null) {
    setState((){
    dropdownValue = value;});
   
}
}, 
)
```

And also please declare `dropdownValue` field in your class as `String? dropdownValue;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `value` for `DropdownButton` and `DropdownMenuItem`

```
DropdownButton(
  value: "Green",
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: "Green",
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Green",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: "Blue",
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Blue",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: "Black",
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Black",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem(
      value: "Red",
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            radius: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text(
            "Red",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
  onChanged: (val) {},
)
```